# Using tmaier/docker-compose in a dockerfile

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose

I would like to use the docker image `tmaier/docker-compose` as it contains docker and docker-compose preinstalled.

I am trying to use the image in a Dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM tmaier/docker-compose:latest

RUN apk add git && 
    cd /home && 
    git clone https://user:password@git.com/test/backend.git && 
    git clone https://user:password@git.com/test/gateway.git
```

Once I am inside the `/home/backend` folder, I'm trying to execute `docker-compose` up, an error message pops up:

```
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?
```

This is the screenshot of the docker and docker-compose permissions in the system

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, follow this post
https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4181

Second thing, try this (and of course add it to your docker file as well once all is working):

Try to restart the docker service:

```
# Restart docker service
sudo service docker restart
```

If it still not working try this

```
# Add user to docker group (if not already added)
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER

# create a symbolic link to /usr/bin using the following command
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose

# Restart docker service
sudo service docker restart
```